# One hot vector in pandas to encode missing values

Tags: python, pandas, nan, one-hot-encoding

I am working with a large pandas dataframe and a few columns have lots of missing data. I am not totally confident with my imputation and I believe the presence or absence of data for these variables could be useful information, so I would like to add another column of the dataframe with 0 where the entry is missing and 1 otherwise. Is there a quick/efficient way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the following:

```py
df['New_Col'] = df['Col'].notna().astype('uint8')
```

Where `Col` it your column containing `np.nan` values and `New_Col` your binary target column indicating whether `Col` contains `np.nan`.

Comment: "0 where the entry is missing" - I guess it should be inverted

Comment: Sorry, then just try df['New_Col'] = (~df['Col'].isna()).astype(int) or df['New_Col'] = df['Col'].notna().astype(int)

Comment: The asker said the dataframe was large so it might make sense to use `notna().astype('uint8')` i.e. make sure the integer is as small as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant function here is `.notna`, which will yield `bool` depending on whether the value is missing or not. To apply it to multiple columns of interest, use:

```py
for c in cols_of_interest:
    df[f'{c}_not_missing'] = 1 * df[c].notna()
```

Note that `1 * bool` will give integer 0/1.